# Github IO page does not load CSS

Tags: dns, web, ssl-certificate, github-pages, hugo

### Question

I would like to understand why my CSS resources are not loaded on my personal Github IO page [tobias-schmidt.site](https://tobias-schmidt.site).

### Issue

When I acess my page via the custom dns [tobias-schmidt.site](https://tobias-schmidt.site) or via the direct github dns mrtobe.github.io the site correctly loads the index.html but not the referenced CSS files. When I click on the blog post it does correctly load the CSS. Then for this surfing session the CSS is also available on the index.html.

### Setup

- dns from GoDaddy with A-Record setup for tobias-schmidt.site - this dns was added in the settings of the github repo
- Website is generated with hugo - full project is hosted under https://github.com/mrtobe/mrtobe-hugo - ./deloy.sh is used to deploy the page
- Hugo generates a static website that is hosted here [https://github.com/mrtobe/mrtobe.github.io](https://github.com/mrtobe/mrtobe.github)

### Best guess

I checked different posts and found that it might be mixed content, but I have no idea on how to solve this with github pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a SSL certificate problem.

> tobias-schmidt.site uses an invalid security certificate.
>
> The certificate is only valid for the following names: *.github.com, github.com, *.github.io
>
> Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

[Github pages doesn't provide HTTPS for custom domains.](https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-github-pages-site-with-https/)

When you access https://tobias-schmidt.site github pages server is sending his certificate which is not valid for your domain and browser are blocking request until you agree using this certificate.

For now, in **conf.toml**, you have to set `baseurl = "http://tobias-schmidt.site"`. This in order to have hugo craft http urls.

In a second time, you can try to [secure you site with services like cloudflare](https://blog.cloudflare.com/secure-and-fast-github-pages-with-cloudflare/) or have a look at [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your fast response David. I will test this today. So the issue is that I can't upload a custom TLS cert at the momenr which means the TLS cert of github will not work because it was signed for mrtobe.github.io. Best T.

Comment: Hello David, I changed the config without success. The CSS is not loaded. Is there any other necessary modification besides the config.toml. Thanks

Comment: Do not call mrtobe.github.io or tobias-schmidt.site with https.

Comment: Alright, I really did use https as it was the custom setting in my browser. Works now - thanks!