# My Octopress blog don't support latex even if I set mathjax in my blog

Tags: latex, mathjax, octopress

I have set my blog to support latex with **MathJax** according to a tutorial [使用kramdown和MathJax给博客添加Latex支持](http://yoyzhou.github.io/blog/2012/08/05/add-latex-support-for-octopress/).

When I rake preview my blog on localhost, the latex formula can display successful. However, It can not work when deploying to `github.io`. Here is my blog site:[my blog site](https://xijunlee.github.io/blog/2016/12/18/man-tan-gao-wei-shu-ju-ju-lei-1/). I have already checked the html code of my site.

There are codes for latex:

```
<script type="math/tex; mode=display">d_{ij}=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}(x_{ik}-x_{jk})^2}</script>
```

It can not work in my site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github IO page does not load CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40827124/github-io-page-does-not-load-css)

Comment: You must load mathjax over https on github pages. Search SO for several duplicates and for mixed content problem in general. (Apologies to the moderators for flagging this poorly.)